Corba and Servlet Implementation
i have an error when i use the servlet to make the communication between my CORBA server project
and my web dynamic project , so i have created my server class of CORBA like this :
   public class NewsServer {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
        NewsImpl newsImpl = new NewsImpl();
        POA rootPOA = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
        rootPOA.activate_object(newsImpl);
        org.omg.CORBA.Object ref = rootPOA.servant_to_reference(newsImpl);
        News newsRef = NewsHelper.narrow(ref);
        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);
        String name = "News";
        NameComponent path[] = ncRef.to_name(name);
        ncRef.rebind(path, newsRef);
        System.out.println("News Server ready...");
        orb.run();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }}

and i have run the server class as java application passing the arguments like this :
- ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost and I have create a web dynamic project with adding a jsp file to make the submit of the title and finally I have create a class servlet to handle the communication between them   :
  public class AddNewsServlet extends HttpServlet {protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest 
   request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String newsTitle = request.getParameter("title");

    try {
        String[] args = {"-ORBInitialPort", "1050", "-ORBInitialHost", "localhost"};
        ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        System.out.println("objRef: " + objRef);
        NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);
        org.omg.CORBA.Object newsObjRef = ncRef.resolve_str("News");
        News newsRef = NewsHelper.narrow(newsObjRef);
        newsRef.addNews(newsTitle);
   

So after running the web project using tomcat and using the url of the project to make the  of a new title i get this error
org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName:IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0
at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1608), i couldn't resolve it any
help please?
